# SQL Syntax Error for 5.5.35-MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am getting the following error message when trying to run some sql code in my 5.5.35-MariaDB. Please can someone help me understand what is wrong?

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `action_recorder` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_I' at line 1

My code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `action_recorder` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`module` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`success` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_action_recorder_module` (`module`),
KEY `idx_action_recorder_user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `idx_action_recorder_identifier` (`identifier`),
KEY `idx_action_recorder_date_added` (`date_added`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci           AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;
```

Please can someone help me resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any queries before this? Make sure you have a `;` between the queries.

Comment: There are no queries before it - this is the first.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing parenthesis. The one at the end is only for the key `idx_action_recorder_date_added`, but you need another one to close the whole table definition.

Also, I think you shouldn't use those normal single quotes. They are for strings. Use backticks or omit them altogether.

Comment: Thanks, I have amended as per your suggestion and this can be seen in my amended question - but I still get the error. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "near..." mentions 'CREATE...', the error is either the `CREATE` or what immediately precedes it.  I vote for the latter -- Look at what have right before it.